# Ionic fails to connect to server

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I was toying with my app, adding the cordova push plugin to the package in one branch, removing it and came back to the master branch. 
Now, building off master the app fails on the ios device with :

```
Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server.
```

And gets stuck in the splash screen. 
The simulator works well. Not sure how what the exact error is and how to solve this? I already removed the ios platform and added it back, deleted the app on the device but it keeps failing.

I cloned the project from cratch

```
npm install
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova prepare ios
ionic cordova run ios  --debug --target="iPhone-X" -l -c
```

but now the simulator fails too. However, I see it is not loading the google map (first view) at all, so I have to dig deeper into that. Thank you for all the suggestions.

On the device I still see 
`Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server.`

Edit - This is not due to the push plugin. I started a fresh project and the problem still prevails, failed to load server on device, simulator works fine.

Comment: can you add screenshot of error ? I have recently added push notification fixed lot of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to clean the project before build before running on the device. This maybe due to the change of `Cordova-plugin-goolemaps` which is now at `2.5.0` and supports browser as well and has to be reconfigured for the device.

Clean Xcode workspace
run 
`ionic cordova build ios`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running this:

`ionic cordova prepare ios`

Answer (score 0):

Which command you used for running app? Means if you have used `ionic serve` then you must have internet connection on device also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command

ionic cordova prepare ios and ionic cordova build ios or ionic cordova run ios

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, other than perhaps "not enough context"? If the generated `platforms` folder already exists, then calling the `run` command will skip the `prepare` and `build` commands _by default_. Calling them explicitly here achieves the same end goal (in this case) of "cleaning" the project first.... :/